# Trying to create user defined function `LIKE` using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am (trying to) using the [sqlite-net-pcl](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) package version 1.8.116, to create a user defined function in C#.

I tried to start simple by creating a function to reverse a string, like [REVERSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

When i try the query: `SELECT 1,'abc','def'`,
I am expecting the output to be: `1:abc:fed`

But the output is: `0:abc:System.Char[]`, So I must have done something wrong...

Can anyone give a tip? because I am pretty clueless right now...

My code:

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection("test.db");

// https://sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html
sqlite3 dbhandle = db.Handle;
string function = "myReverse";
int narg = 1;
int eTextRep = SQLitePCL.raw.SQLITE_UTF8 | SQLitePCL.raw.SQLITE_DETERMINISTIC;

int ok = SQLitePCL.raw.sqlite3_create_function(dbhandle, function, narg, eTextRep, myReverse);
//Console.WriteLine($"OK:{ok}");

SQLiteCommand cmd = db.CreateCommand("SELECT 1 as id, 'abc' as t, myReverse('def') as revt");
var result = cmd.ExecuteQuery<Record>();
Console.WriteLine($"{result[0].id}:{result[0].t}:{result[0].revt}");
```

and:

```
static void myReverse(sqlite3_context ctx, object user_data, sqlite3_value[] args)
{
    SQLitePCL.utf8z utf8z = raw.sqlite3_value_text(args[0]);
    string input = utf8z.utf8_to_string();
    //Console.WriteLine($"INPUT:{input}");  // This shows INPUT:def
    char[] charArray = input.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    //raw.sqlite3_result_text(ctx, utf8z.FromString(charArray.ToString())); // see: comments...
    raw.sqlite3_result_text(ctx, utf8z.FromString(new string(charArray)));
}
```

Record:

```
    public class Record
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string t { get; set; }
        public string revt { get; set; }
    }
```

Above was my first try, finally I would like to have an implementation of the function LIKE, like is mentioned in [paragraph 5](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) "The infix LIKE operator is implemented by calling the application-defined SQL functions"

Currently returning a string is working, but I am looking for something like `raw.sqlite3_result_boolean`, or `raw.sqlite3_result_logical`, because the return value for the function LIKE is a boolean.

Comment: No kidding. That's because `charArray.ToString()` returns `System.Char[]`. Why don't you create a string from the characters, like `new string(charArray)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough experience with C# to have spotted that after scratching my head because doing this with the `microsoft.data.sqlite` package is soo much easier!